# Yii Captcha Action change colors randomly

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I decided to make Yii captcha render random colors for background and foreground, so I had made the following change to the public method `actions` in the `SiteController` where the captcha is going to be rendered in the `actionContcat` view.

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Declares class-based actions.
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
            'captcha'=>array(
                'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
                'backColor'=>$this->setRandColor('DARK'),
                'foreColor'=>$this->setRandColor('LIGHT'),
            ),
            // page action renders "static" pages stored under 'protected/views/site/pages'
            // They can be accessed via: index.php?r=site/page&view=FileName
            'page'=>array(
                'class'=>'CViewAction',
            ),
        );
    }
...
```

In the code above I have make the backColor and foreColor keys values are the return of a private method `setRandColor`. The following is the method code:

```
/**
     * Generate random hexadecimal color code in format 0xXXXXXX according to type param
     * which has only two values DARK and LIGHT
     * @param string $type
     */
    private  function setRandColor($type='DARK')
    {
        $color = '0x';
        $darks = array(0,1,3,4,5,6,7);
        $lights = array(9,'A','B','C','D','E','F');
        if ($type == 'DARK')
        {
            $chooseFrom = $darks;
        }
        else 
        {
            $chooseFrom = $lights;
        }           
        for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
        {
            $color .= $chooseFrom[array_rand($chooseFrom)];         
        }
        return $color;      
    }
```

I have tested `setRandColor` alone. i.e in plain php script and I found it works fine to return the hexadecimal code. Look at the following Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/OcCSjL

However, when using the described code above I just get a black captcha image with no any error messages. I need to know why this code do not work in my Yii application?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the problem. The problem is the type of the returned value from `setRandColor` method. The method returns string value, while the captcha array requires hexadecimal value.

I solved this issue by modifying the last line of `setRandColor` in which it returns the value as follows:

```
return $color/1;
```

By this way I casted the type from string to be number.